# os.rename() VS os.replace() (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ос, replace

Разбираюсь с модулем os. Пытаюсь понять, чем отличаются функции os.rename() и os.replace(). Пытался переименовать файл с их помощью, получаю одинаковый результат. Когда пытаюсь переименовать и папку и файл одновременно, что там, что там получаю ошибку. Так чем же они отличаются? Приведите пожалуйста пример, когда rename() и replace() работают по-разному.

Comment: "rename() и replace() работают по-разному" - когда целевой файл существует. Один выдаст ошибку, а другой молча перезапишет.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename и https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename(file1,file2) - только переименовывает файл file1 в file2
replace(file1,file2) - если файл(file2) уже существуют, то он его перезаписывает file2 из file1

если использовать rename во втором случае, то выйдет ошибка